# IDが紐づいている別テーブルのレーコード件数を取得したい

Tags: sql

以下のように、tableAのIDに紐づくtableBがあります。
これらのテーブルに対してtableAの結果全てと、tableAのIDに紐づいているtableBの件数を、下記希望取得結果のような形で取得できるSQLはあるでしょうか？
現在の想定では、tableAの結果をループで回してtableBの件数を取得するしかないかなと考えています。

```
tableA
id | name
ーーーーーーー
1  | 山田太郎
2  | 鈴木次郎
3  | 田中三郎


tableB
id | tableA_id
ーーーーーーー
1  | 1
2  | 1
3  | 1
4  | 3


希望取得結果
1  | 山田太郎 | 3
2  | 鈴木次郎 | 0
3  | 田中三郎 | 1
```

Comment: 参考: [count in LEFT JOIN and WHERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949208/count-in-left-join-and-where)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

考え方ですがまず`tableB`をグループ化してカウントします。

```
SELECT tableA_id, COUNT(*) FROM tableB GROUP BY tableA_id
```

件数が得られます。

```
1 | 3
3 | 1
```

`tableA`にこの結果を左結合します。

```
SELECT id, name, cnt
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tableA_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tableB GROUP BY tableA_id)
ON id = tableA_id
```

これで希望にかなり近い結果が得られます。

```
1 | 山田太郎 | 3
2 | 鈴木次郎 | NULL
3 | 田中三郎 | 1
```

左結合で結合されなかった行には`NULL`となるため、これを`0`にすれば希望する結果が得られます。

```
SELECT id, name, COALESCE(cnt, 0)
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT tableA_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tableB GROUP BY tableA_id)
ON id = tableA_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.name, grouped_b.Counted
  from tableA a
  left join
  (select tableA_id, COUNT(id) AS Counted from tableB group by tableA_id) grouped_b
    ON a.id=b.tableA_id
```

Answer (score -1):

シンブルに `tableA` をベースに件数だけ副問合せします。
`tableA` の件数が多くなければこれで十分です。

```sql
select
  id,
  name,
  (
    select
      count(*)
    from
      tableB
    where
      tableB.tableA_id = tableA.id
  ) as count
from
  tableA;
```